# Javascript touch events to move image left or right not working

Tags: javascript, touch, touch-event

**EDIT: I've added two console.logs, one before the touchmove function, and another in the touchmove function, and they are both giving the same value of touch.pageX, so touch.pageX is not changing at all. I don't know why it isn't.**

I'm trying to use `touchstart` and `touchmove` events to move an image left or right on a page.

Here's the function that fires when the image is touched. The `console.log` statements are firing, so they are executing, but the image is not moving. The `console.log` within the `touchmove` event listener function is continuously firing when the touch point is moved, which I'm guessing is the desired behavior.

```
// event listener on an image that gets touched
lightboxImages[i].addEventListener('touchstart', touchMove);

  function touchMove(event) {

    console.log('touch.pageX');

    event.preventDefault();
    var touchedImage = event.target;
    var touch = event.touches[0];
    var moveOffsetX = touchedImage.offsetLeft - touch.pageX;

    touchedImage.addEventListener('touchmove', function() {

      console.log('touch.pageX');
      var positionX = touch.pageX + moveOffsetX;
      touchedImage.style.left = positionX + 'px';
    }, false);
  }
```

In the dom, this seems to change the `left` value of the image touched to `left: 0`, but doesn't result in any physical movement of the image on the page since the image has 100% width and takes up the full width of the page.

Because the image is already 100% width of the page, I'm trying to get this movement to basically shift the page off the screen. I'm not sure what is preventing the `left` value from being anything other than `0`.

Some of this code was taken from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3b1rvuFCJY

Comment: try removing `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: No change unfortunately